# screen-responsive navbar can't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have navigation bar for pc and for mobile, problem is if I maximize window when mobile navbar is opened, mobile navbar will disappear as it should but desktop navbar doesn't appear. I am working with bootstrap template and I don't know if my problem solution requires javascript knowledge but if it does, I can show it.
**Here is my css code**

```
/**
* Desktop Navigation 
*/
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a,
.navbar a:focus {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #751D41;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a.active { color: #751D41}

.navbar a:hover,
.navbar .active,
.navbar .active:focus,
.navbar li:hover>a {
  color: #402D85;
}

.navbar .getintouch,
.navbar .getintouch:focus {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #751D41;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 2px solid #751D41;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .getintouch:hover,
.navbar .getintouch:focus:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #751D41;
}

/**
* Mobile Navigation 
*/
.navbar-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle.bi-x {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar-mobile {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 55px;
    right: 20px;
    left: 10;
    bottom: 150px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    z-index: 999;
  }
}

.navbar-mobile .mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.navbar-mobile ul {
  display: block;
  top: 55px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(253, 110, 110, 0.5);
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar-mobile a,
.navbar-mobile a:focus {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-mobile a:hover,
.navbar-mobile .active,
.navbar-mobile li:hover>a {
  color: #751D41;
}

.navbar-mobile .getintouch,
.navbar-mobile .getintouch:focus {
  margin: 15px;
  color: #402D85;
}
```

**and here is html code**

```
<!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top ">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">

      <a href="#hero" class="logo me-auto"><img src="assets/img/navLogo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#hero">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#hero">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#hero">Our Team</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#hero">Our Offers</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#hero">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#hero">Careers</a></li>
          <li><a class="getintouch scrollto" href="#hero">Get In Touch</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav><!-- .navbar -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->
```

[image: WHEN MOBILE NAVIGATION BAR IS OPEN]

[image: IF I MAXIMIZE WINDOW]

[image: PC NAVIGATION BAR DOESN'T APPEAR]

Comment: where is your html code to fix this issue add your HTML and CSS code combine which working same as in photos so that people will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your Header and edit accordingly you want it, its responsive too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Toggle menu on click
  $("#menu-toggler").click(function() {
    toggleBodyClass("menu-active");
  });

  function toggleBodyClass(className) {
    document.body.classList.toggle(className);
  }

 });
```

```css
/* Extra */
$primary: #fff;
$secondary: #ccc;
$ternary: #272727;
$dark: #444444;

body {
  background: $secondary;
  color: $ternary;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;

}

.logo {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.navbar {
  align-items: center;
  background: $primary;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

.push-left {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* Menu */
.hamburger {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  &-line {
    background: $ternary;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .2s ease-out; 
    width: 100%;
    
    .hamburger:hover & {
      background: #777;
    }
    
    &-top {
      top: 3px;
    }
    
    .menu-active &-top {
      top: 50%;
      transform: rotate(45deg) translatey(-50%);
    }
    
    &-middle {
      top: 50%;
      transform: translatey(-50%);
    }
    
    .menu-active &-middle {
      left: 50%;
      opacity: 0;
      width: 0;
    }

    &-bottom {
      bottom: 3px;
    }

    .menu-active &-bottom {
      bottom: 50%;
      transform: rotate(-45deg) translatey(50%);
    }
  }
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .25s ease-in; 
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    background: $primary;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    transform: translatey(-100%);
    text-align: center;
    
    .menu-active & {
      transform: translatey(0%);  
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .menu-item a {
    color: $dark;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
    &:hover {
      color: lighten($dark, 20);
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 8px;
    }
  }
  
  
}

.sub-nav {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: $primary;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    list-style: none; 
    width: 230px;   
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}

 .nav__link {
   &:hover + .sub-nav {
        display:block;

 }
}

.sub-nav {
  &:hover {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/AS_sample_logo.png" alt="LOGO"></div>
  <div class="push-left">
    <button id="menu-toggler" data-class="menu-active" class="hamburger">
      <span class="hamburger-line hamburger-line-top"></span>
      <span class="hamburger-line hamburger-line-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamburger-line hamburger-line-bottom"></span>
    </button>

    <!--  Menu compatible with wp_nav_menu  -->
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
       <li class="menu-item "><a class="nav__link"  href="#">Home</a>  
      </li>     
      <li class="menu-item "><a class="nav__link"  href="#">About Us</a>  
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item "><a class="nav__link"  href="#">Our Team</a>  
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item "><a class="nav__link"  href="#">Our Offers</a>  
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item "><a class="nav__link"  href="#">Projects</a>  
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item "><a class="nav__link"  href="#">Careers</a>  
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item "><a class="nav__link"  href="#">Get In Touch</a>  
      </li>
    </ul>


  </div>
</nav>
```